# how to change $_SESSION['user_login'] to laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

hello guys i'm new user for laravel, can someone help me , how to change this code to laravel

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_login'] = false;
  }
?>
```

Comment: You can read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#retrieving-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let me give it a shot,

```
<?php
  session_start(); // This is default taken care by laravel no need for that

  // Here we can work something
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_login'] = false;
  }

  // This Laravel version

  use Session; // top of the file after namespace deceleration 

  if (Session::has('user_login'))) {
    Session::set('user_login', false);
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been quite a long time I didn’t handle session related data. But if it is Laravel, if I am not wrong then there has a method `session` which proxies calls to `Session` facade. 

So, you'll need

```
session()->put('user_login', session('user_login', false));
```

Put `session` `user_login` to what it already has otherwise `false`