# how to change !isset($_SESSION['user_login']) to laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
     $_SESSION['user_login'] = false;
 }
?>
```

hello guys can someone help me , how to change this session to laravel ?

Comment: you want check that user is logged in or not?

Comment: There are some laravel way for changing user login session.

Comment: Why are you posting duplicate questions ? with slight change in question name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session) for this case:

```
use Session; 

if (Session::has('user_login'))) {
} else {
  Session::set('user_login', false); // this will be your case because you have specified `!` i.e not set
}
```

or in newer versions of Laravel you can determine if `user_login` exists in the Session via `$request`:

```
if ($request->session()->has('user_login')) {
    //
} else {
    $request->session()->put('user_login', 'false');
}
```

Comment: I would assume that OP is trying to make a switch from raw/vanilla PHP to Laravel and asking for the Laravel equivalent of the snippet in question. But I could be entirely wrong.

Comment: @Tanmay he has mentioned in his question `how to change this session to laravel` so you can assume that he wants equivalent laravel code for the given code!

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel, you have to check user logged in or not by using the **Auth**.

Like this:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // if user is logged in.
}

if (Auth::guest()) {
    // if user is not logged in.
}
```

Comment: OP is asking how to convert `is not set session` to laravel. Not to check authentication!

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate question for duplicate answer [how to change $_SESSION['user_login'] to laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54949282/5928015)

```
 <?php
      session_start(); // This is default taken care by laravel no need for that

      // Here we can work something
      if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_login'] = false;
      }

      // This Laravel version

      use Session; // top of the file after namespace deceleration 

      if (Session::has('user_login'))) {
        Session::set('user_login', false);
      } 
    ?>
```

I hope this helps.